# Building decompiled APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, decompiler, apktool

I purchased a smart medical device by a company called Contec to help monitor my grandfather's health (specifically, a urinalysis tester - he has kidney failure). The device is great, but the Android app itself ([com.contec.phms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contec.phms)) is abysmal - it will collect readings from the devices via Bluetooth, but there is no way to export the data to take to the doctor. I have tried contacting the app developers, but they have not responded.

I am pretty handy with Linux, but I can't figure out how to interface with these products without the app. I'm not much of an Android developer, but I know enough to hack small changes to existing apps. If I could decompile this app, I'm sure I could trace the data and at least figure out a way to export to CSV. I have tried a few common decompilers, but I can't get the app to cleanly build in Android Studio. I don't know if this is against forum rules since this is for personal use, but could someone help?

Comment: It might not be even legal

Comment: Perhaps, but for personal use with no intention to distribute, I'm not sure there is a problem. I just can't figure any other way to get data off the device.